# ${}$ Electric Charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, distance

We have two positive point charges, moving toward each other, with velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$. How to prove (mathematicaly) that their distance will be minimum, when their velocities become equal? The initial distance is $d$.

From conservation of energy we can write:

$\frac{m_1 v_1^2}{2} + \frac{m_2 v_2^2}{2} + \frac{kq_1q_2}{d} = \frac {m_1u_1^2}{2} + \frac{m_2u_2^2}{2} + \frac{kq_1q_2}{r} $

We can write this as:
$E=\frac{m_1 v_1^2}{2} + \frac{m_2 v_2^2}{2} + \frac{kq_1q_2}{d}$

$E_k = \frac{m_1u_1^2}{2} + \frac{m_2u_2^2}{2} $

$E=E_k + \frac{kq_1q_2}{r}$

So, $E$ is constant, and $r$ is min when $E_k$ is min.

Also, from conservation of momentum we have:

$ p = m_1v_1 + m_2v_2$

Can we use arithmetic-geometric inequality to get the minimum of $E_k = \frac{m_1u_1^2}{2} + \frac{m_2u_2^2}{2} $ ? Why, why not?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. By the way, how did you come to know about the above fact that the distance will be minimum if the velocities become equal? And could you please furnish some more details in your question so that we can help you out?

Comment: @DeepBhowmik Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question, and found a solution in a textbook but withut explanation. I am just woundering if we can apply arithmetic-geometric inequality (why , why not) to find the relation bewtween the velocities $u_1$ and $u_2$ ?  (They should be equal)